# using ng-class with large expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, font-awesome

I'm using ng-class to show an approapriate font awesome Icon, but after several months, the expression used by ng-class has be come unwieldy to maintain and annoying to try and read:

```
<span ng-class="{'fa fa-close iconBlack':stain.StainStatus == 'Canceled', 'fa fa-exclamation-circle iconRed': stain.StainStatus == 'Missing', 'fa fa-clock-o iconOrange':stain.StainStatus == 'Ordered' || stain.StainStatus == 'Printed' || stain.StainStatus == 'In Process', 'fa fa-check iconGreen': stain.StainStatus == 'Verified' || stain.StainStatus == 'Completed', 'fa fa-pause iconPurple stainPauseIconFontSize': stain.StainStatus == 'On Hold', 'fa fa-ban iconRed':stain.Count > 1 && modifyModeActive}"></span>
```

One solution would be to put each icon into their own <span> and then just use ng-show/hide on the spans as needed, but I was wondering what other ways there are to maintain a large ng-class expression like this?

Comment: How about export the ngClass configuration object into your controller? It would be easier to maintain and keep your html simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) accepts any expression so you can put the class definition object into a controller and replace it with a function call:

```
<span ng-class="getMyClasses()"></span>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.getMyClasses = function() {
    return {
        'fa fa-close iconBlack':stain.StainStatus == 'Canceled',
        'fa fa-exclamation-circle iconRed': stain.StainStatus == 'Missing',
        'fa fa-clock-o iconOrange':stain.StainStatus == 'Ordered' || stain.StainStatus == 'Printed' || stain.StainStatus == 'In Process',
        'fa fa-check iconGreen': stain.StainStatus == 'Verified' || stain.StainStatus == 'Completed',
        'fa fa-pause iconPurple stainPauseIconFontSize': stain.StainStatus == 'On Hold',
        'fa fa-ban iconRed':stain.Count > 1 && modifyModeActive
    }
}
```

This might have some performance issues because it has to create the object on every digest call so you could create the object just once and return only its reference. Then update it manually when you know it might have changed.

Comment: The answer you have is good, though the suggestion to just have it return a reference to a singleton won't work because the the individual properties of it will be set (e.g. `'fa fa-close iconBlack'` will be `true` or `false`, _not_ `stain.StainStatus == 'Cancelled'`. The function way is correct, and while putting function calls in the view is generally discouraged, should work.